# Exception in Application start method JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Не могу исправить ошибку

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=57115:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p C:\Users\Bair\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Users\Bair\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;C:\Users\Bair\IdeaProjects\StudHelpServer\out\production\StudHelpServer;C:\Users\Bair\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Users\Bair\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Users\Bair\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Users\Bair\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Users\Bair\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Users\Bair\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.web.jar -m StudHelpServer/sample.Main
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method on primary stage
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:447)
    at StudHelpServer/sample.Main.start(Main.java:24)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Вот мой мэйн, мб проблема в нем в строке Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url); хотя не уверен.

```
package sample;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    import java.net.URL;

    public class Main extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

            URL url = getClass().getResource("/sample/View/AdminPage.fxml");
            if(url == null){
                System.out.println("cant open file");
            }
            else {
                Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
                primaryStage.setTitle("StudServer");
                primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                primaryStage.showAndWait();
            }
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

My fxmlFile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fafafa;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TextArea fx:id="workConsole" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="380.0" prefWidth="483.0" />
      <Button fx:id="startButton" layoutX="507.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="79.0" text="Start" />
      <Button fx:id="closeButton" layoutX="507.0" layoutY="352.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="79.0" text="Close" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Это контроллер

```
package sample.Controllers;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import sample.Servers.Server;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TextArea workConsole;

    @FXML
    private Button startButton;

    @FXML
    private Button closeButton;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert workConsole != null : "fx:id=\"workConsole\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'AdminPage.fxml'.";
        assert startButton != null : "fx:id=\"startButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'AdminPage.fxml'.";
        assert closeButton != null : "fx:id=\"closeButton\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'AdminPage.fxml'.";

        workConsole.setEditable(false);
        Server.server.setWorkConsole(workConsole);

        startButton.setOnAction(event -> {

            if(!Server.server.isWorkServer()) {
                Server.server.start();
            }
            Server.server.showMessage("Server has been started");

        });

        closeButton.setOnAction(event -> {

            try {
                Server.server.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Server.server.showMessage("Cannot close server " + e.toString());
            }

        });

    }
}
```

P.S.
Облазил весь StackOverFlow но так и не понял в чем ошибка.

Comment: Забыл добавить в fxml файл кусок кода fx:controller="sample.Controllers.Controller" Но он не важен в принципе, без него и с ним ошибку выдает эту же

Comment: Простите, но Вы вообще читали описание ошибки? Там все более, чем понятно написано.

Comment: Можете пояснить пожалуйста? Я недавно начал изучать java так что мне не понятно